# Parsing nmap xml report with python

Tags: python, xml, nmap

I am trying to extract some elements from the following XML file (trimmed down `nmap` output):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nmaprun>
<host starttime="1381245200" endtime="1381245316">
    <address addr="192.168.1.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
    <hostnames>
      <hostname name="host1.example.com" type="PTR"/>
    </hostnames>
    <os>
        <osmatch>
        <osclass type="general purpose" vendor="Linux" osfamily="Linux" osgen="2.6.X" accuracy="100">
          <cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6</cpe>
        </osclass>
      </osmatch>
    </os>
  </host>
</nmaprun>
```

with the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

d = [
        {'path': 'address', 'el': 'addr'},
        {'path': 'hostnames/hostname', 'el': 'name'},
        {'path': 'os/osmatch/osclass', 'el': 'osfamily'}
]

tree = ET.parse('testnmap.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for i in root.iter('host'):
        for h in d:
                if i.find(h['path']): print i.find(h['path']).get(h['el'])
                else: print "UNKNOWN ", (h['path'])
```

The idea being to extract the IP, hostname and OS. The output gives me

```
UNKNOWN  address
UNKNOWN  hostnames/hostname
Linux
```

So the innermost path worked (osfamily), while the others (hostname) failed. What should be the proper call to reach them?

Comment: As an alternative, consider using the parser included in the Ndiff Python script that is distributed with Nmap. It is specifically designed for parsing Nmap XML and returning the results in Python objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the boolean comparison of `i.find(h['path'])`. It checks if that element has children, and it only happens in `<osclass>`. You have to check if it's null, comparing to `None`, like:

```
...
e = i.find(h['path'])
if e is not None: print(e.get(h['el']))
...
```

It yields:

```
192.168.1.5
host1.example.com
Linux
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand: what is the difference between calling `i.find("os/osmatch/osclass")` and `i.find("hostnames/hostname")`, the  .get() afterwards reaches for elements within the tag in both cases (what I mean is that they get the "aaa" value from `<tag aaa="bbb">`). Your code works and solves the problem -- it's just i do understand why it works :)

Comment: @Woj: As I understand it, when an element exists but has no children it returns `False`, and when the element doesn't exist return `None`. In boolean context both values are interpreted as `False`, so an explicit check with `None` is needed to filter those elements that cannot be found. So, `<hostname>` was `UNKNOWN` because it has no children but `<osclass>` had one, the `<cpe>`.

Comment: all is clear now -- I did not realize that there were two different values returned depending on children existence, both `False` for an `if`. Thanks for the clarification!